# what's the difference between track and trail

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

When track and trail refer to following something, are they identical?

For example,

> I followed him, tracking him in the snow until finally he got tired.
>
> I trailed her to a shop in Kensington.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, [to *track*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/track) means to actively search for things like footprints or marks, to follow the route someone or something has taken.

> The hunters **tracked** the bear deep into the forest, where they found its den

Meanwhile [to *trail*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trail) means to follow someone or something's route, possibly by *tracking* it, or by keeping it in visual range.

> The little boy **trailed** behind his older sister, complaining that his feet hurt.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Therefore their meaning mostly overlaps. Could I use them interchangeably?@Andrew

Comment: @Young  No.  *Tracking* is actively looking for signs and following them, while *trailing* is simply following someone or something.  The meanings overlap, but they are not the same.